# Monotonicity of functions in a parametric family

Tags: real-analysis

In tackling [a recent Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143686/show-two-functions-are-uniformly-comparable-on-the-real-line) I twice bumped into the following family of functions for $\alpha \in [0,2]$:

$$  f_\alpha(x) = \cos \alpha x - \cos^\alpha x  $$

Each $f_\alpha$ satisfies $f_\alpha(0) = 0$, is continuous on $[0,\pi/2]$, and is analytic there except at $x=\pi/2$.

I conjecture each $f_\alpha$ is monotone on $(0,\pi/2)$.

Specifically $f_0 = f_1 = 0$ and:

$$ f_2(x) = \cos 2x - \cos^2 x = \cos^2 x - 1 $$

The functions $f_\alpha$ appear to be strictly increasing for $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$ and strictly decreasing for $1 \lt \alpha \lt 2$.

How do we show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
f_\alpha'(x)=\alpha(\cos^{\alpha-1}x\sin x-\sin(\alpha\,x)).
$$

**1**. $0<\alpha<1$. Then $0<\alpha\,x<x$, $0<\sin(\alpha\,x)<\sin x$ for all $x\in(0,\pi/2)$ and
$$
f_\alpha'(x)>\alpha\sin(\alpha\,x)(\cos^{\alpha-1}x-1)>0,
$$
since $\alpha-1<0$ and $\cos^{\alpha-1}x>1$.

**2.** $1<\alpha\le2$. I want to show that
$$
\cos^{\alpha-1}x\sin x\le\sin(\alpha\,x),\quad0<x<\frac\pi2.
$$
Since $0<\alpha-1\le 1$,
$$
\sin(\alpha\,x)=\sin x\cos((\alpha-1)\,x)+\cos x\sin((\alpha-1)\,x)\ge\sin x\cos((\alpha-1)\,x),\quad0<x<\frac\pi2,
$$
it is enough to show that
$$
\cos^{\alpha-1}x\le\cos((\alpha-1)\,x),\quad0<x<\frac\pi2.
$$
This follows from the fact that the inequality holds at $x=0$ and
$$
(\cos^{\alpha-1}x)'\le(\cos((\alpha-1)\,x))',\quad0<x<\frac\pi2.
$$
The last inequality is true because $\alpha-2\le0$ and
$$
\cos^{\alpha-2}x\sin x\ge\sin(\alpha-1)x,\quad0<x<\frac\pi2.
$$

Comment: Nicely done!  Note that in the second case, the proposition that $$ \cos^{\alpha - 1} x \le \cos((\alpha -1) x) $$ may be referred back to the increasing of $f_{\alpha -1}$ established in the first part.  The relationship of these two subdomains led me to suspect there might be a functional equation satisfied by the family $f_\alpha$, but that remains only a suspicion.